# Проблема с string (c++) в VSCode

Tags: c++, строки, visual-studio-code

Здравствуйте. Такой вопрос. Начал изучать с++. В VSCode при добавлении любого значения типа string при запуске ехе получаю такую ошибку. Кто-то может быть знает как это исправить. В с++ я очень новичок, возможно что-то очевидное упускаю. [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Код программы:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
struct Vector 
{
    float x, y, z; // положения x, y и z все типа float
}; 

struct Player
{
    //string name;
    int hp;
    Vector position;
}; 

int main()
{
// создаём объект типа Player,
    Player me; // экземпляру дано имя 'me'
    //me.name = "William";
    me.hp = 100.0f;
    me.position.x = me.position.y = me.position.z=0;
    string name = "LOOL";

    cout << name <<endl;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Task.json:

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "taskName": "build hello world",
            "type": "shell",
            "command": "g++",
            "args": [
                "-g", "${file}"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

c_cpp_properies.json:

```
{
"configurations": [
    {
        "name": "Win32",
        "includePath": [
            "${workspaceRoot}",
            "C:\\MinGW\\lib\\gcc\\mingw32\\6.3.0\\include\\c++"
        ],
        "defines": [
            "_DEBUG",
            "UNICODE"
        ],
        "intelliSenseMode": "msvc-x64",
        "browse": {
            "path": [
                "${workspaceRoot}",
                "C:\\MinGW\\lib\\gcc\\mingw32\\6.3.0\\include\\c++"
            ],
            "limitSymbolsToIncludedHeaders": true,
            "databaseFilename": ""
        }
    }
],
"version": 3
}
```

launch.json:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [

        {
            "name": "(gdb) Launch",
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${workspaceRoot}/a.exe",
            "args": [],
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
            "environment": [],
            "externalConsole": true,
            "MIMode": "gdb",
            "miDebuggerPath": "C:\\MinGW\\bin\\gdb.exe",
            "setupCommands": [
                {
                    "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
                    "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
                    "ignoreFailures": true
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Возможно тебе надо указать библиотеку как ещё один параметр в командной строке сборки (не компиляции) проекта. Как пишут сами micosoft'ы класс string вызывает сбои и повреждение памяти на многопроцессорных компьютерах

Comment: Решил скомпилировать через командную строку. Ввел g++ main.cpp. Файл запускается без ошибок и работает со string адекватно. Видимо проблема именно связанная с VSCode

Comment: ну это уже к компилятору =)) а может и нет

Comment: Случилось чудо. Я случайно за компилировал launch.json(конечно же вывелась ошибка), но после этого VSCode начал компилировать его адекватно)))

Comment: поздравляю, наверное все-таки дело было в компиляторе=))

Comment: Да, теперь только разобрался. Вся проблема была в компиляторе MinGW. Установил cygwin и все заработало. Спасибо за совет))